# How do I access an array of objects of arrays?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, flex3, flexbuilder

I have a chart and am trying to display the "volume" in a line chart as the primary series & the "temp" as a column chart as the secondary series...(the "compound" will be shown in the datatip):

```
[{date=Tue Feb 08 19:00:00 EST 2011, volume=1200, 1={temp=-50, compound=helium}, 0={temp=-45, compound=oxygen}}]
```

I can get the "volume" series to display fine, but cannot get the "temp" series to display...how do I access them? Right now I have:

```
<mx:ColumnSeries id="secondSeries" xField="date" yField="temp">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't know which datatpype your Object is.

I use an Array for example. Check this Code:

```
<fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            private var obj:Array = [{date:"Tue Feb 08 19:00:00 EST 2011", volume:"1200", 1:{temp:"-50", compound:"helium"}, 0:{temp:"-45", compound:"oxygen"}}];


            private function onInit() :void
            {
                trace (obj[0].date);
                trace (obj[0][1].temp);

            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
```

Let me know, if you're using another Datatype.

BR
Frank

Comment: well, I need it to be dynamic because the number of "temps" and "compounds" will vary...sometimes I will have 2 (as in the example above), sometimes I'll have 20 & sometimes none.

Comment: The data is from a mysql database that is brought in through php/Zend

Comment: the dynamic comes from a for loop depend on obj.[0][1].length for a script solution. However, a barchart should draw each object dynamically. If you need more info, please let me know. But please post more code

Comment: but how do I access those series in a column chart?

Comment: Hi User522962, as i wrote, please post more code. I need to know, what a datatype you use as dataprovider. After that, i can post an example. BR Frank